# Inserting Dataframe to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the below:

```
import pandas as pd

student_dict = {
"ID":[101,102,103,104,105],
"Student":["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE"],
"Mark":[50,100,99,60,80],
"Address":["St.AAA","St.BBB","St.CCC","St.DDD","St.EEE"],
"PhoneNo":[1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(student_dict)

ID  Student Mark    Address PhoneNo
101 AAA       50    St.AAA  1111111111
102 BBB      100    St.BBB  2222222222
103 CCC       99    St.CCC  3333333333
104 DDD       60    St.DDD  4444444444
105 EEE       80    St.EEE  5555555555
```

MySql table(`StudentTable`):

```
CREATE TABLE StudentTable(
    ID int,
    Student varchar(255),
    Mark int,
    Address varchar(255),
    PhoneNo varchar(20),
    primary key (ID)
);
```

For inserting the dataframe `df` into the `MySQL` table I used:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname')

# Create the connection and close it(whether successed of failed)
with engine.begin() as connection:
    df.to_sql(name='StudentTable', con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

and the dataframe successfully inserted[image: StudentTable], if I try to insert another `df` like:

```
student_dict2 = {
"ID":[122,102,123],
"Student":["XXX","YYY","ZZZ"],
"Mark":[60,80,95],
"Address":["St.XXX","St.YYY","St.ZZZ"],
"PhoneNo":[1111111110,2222222222,3333333315]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(student_dict2)

ID  Student Mark    Address PhoneNo
122 XXX       60    St.XXX  1111111110
102 YYY       80    St.YYY  2222222222
123 ZZZ       95    St.ZZZ  3333333315
```

it will throw an error like

```
IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '102' for key 'StudentTable.PRIMARY'")
```

It won't insert the other rows into the `StudentTable` which are not duplicates.
What I need is, **it needs to insert the non-duplicate rows into the table and *throw an error only for the duplicate rows*. and is there any way to create a Timestamp column in the `StudentTable` that will auto-capture the data insertion time**

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE StudentTable(
    ID int,
    Student varchar(255),
    Mark int,
    Address varchar(255),
    PhoneNo varchar(20),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    primary key (ID) 
);
```

I think this is how you can create a timestamp column that will capture the data insertion time to the best of my knowledge.

And about inserting only those elements which are not duplicates, I am not sure but I think you should iterate over each row in student_dict and ignore those rows which has duplicate id in them.